# Specify implement interface on derived class when base class implements it abtract

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I was wondering if there are any (runtime) difference if I implement an interface on a derived class if the base abstract class implements it already abstract:

```
public interface IFoo
{
  void Bar();
}

public abstract class Base : IFoo
{
  public abstract void Bar();
}

public class Derived : Base, IFoo // does this make any difference?
{
  public override void Bar()
  {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Is there any difference writing the "implemention" `IFoo` on `Derived` for example when I check if an instance implements an interface at runtime etc.?

Comment: No, for the derived class, implementing IFoo is redundant since the Base class already implements it.

Comment: It does not make any difference rather this is redundant to implement it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider following on your example. Must the following be possible?

```
void f(Base b){
    IFoo ifoo = b;
}
```

Because an object b is a Base, it must be an IFoo because Base implements IFoo. Now consider the following.

```
var d = new Derived();
f(d);
```

Since d is a Derived, it is a Base, because derived inherits from Base. Because of this, we can pass it to f, where it is then assigned to an IFoo, as we did before.

Essentially, because a derived class still is also all of its base classes, it already implements all of its base classes' interfaces. The designers of the language acknowledged this and there is no need to redeclare that a derived class is implementing interfaces that are implemented by its base classes.

I guess that maybe your question arises because of where you actually put the method body, but that really isn't relevant. The declaration of the interface is a contract for other consumers of objects of that type. Those consumers don't care where the method body was defined, all that they care is that when they have an IFoo, that it has a method with the signature `void Bar()` that can be called, as I showed earlier, inheritance must include all interfaces, so there is no need to declare them again.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is **No**. There is no difference.

The Class `Derived` inherits from `Base` and `Base` in turn implements `IFoo`.

So, there is no necessity for you to "implement" both `Base` and `IFoo` when defining the class `Derived`.

The hierarchy is established when you are defining the class `Base`:

`public abstract class Base : IFoo`

and continued when you define `Derived` as below:

`public abstract class Derived : Base`

---

The only problem may arise when you "Remove" `Base` from the hierarchy by redefining the `Base` class by removing the  **`: IFoo`** implementation from the `Base` class definition as below:

`public abstract class Base`

---

The bottom line is: **`, IFoo`** is redundant and is therefore not necessary.

Comment: Awesome! I like your way of answering, first you answered the question, highlighted it and gave a brief explanation then an in-depth explanation

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle difference.

Consider this code:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}

public abstract class Base : IFoo
{
    void IFoo.Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Implicit");
    }
}

public class Derived1 : Base, IFoo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Explicit");
    }
}


public class Derived2 : Base, IFoo { }
```

If I then run this:

```
var d1 = new Derived1();
var d2 = new Derived2();
var b1 = (Base)d1;
var b2 = (Base)d2;

d1.Bar();
(b1 as IFoo).Bar();
(b2 as IFoo).Bar();
```

I get:

```
Explicit
Explicit
Implicit
```

The `void IFoo.Bar()` on `Base` is effectively hidden when implemented explicitly in the derived class. No compiler warning.